# The fetch fonction load infinitely (Shopify)

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, fetch, local-storage

I have try this but I wasn't able to add a cookie or locale storage condition so it won't reload infinitely.

```
fetch('https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country')
.then(response => response.text())
.then(country_code => {


    var domain_and_tld = window.location.host.split('.').splice(-2).join('.');
    country_code = country_code.trim().toLowerCase();

    switch (country_code) {
        case 'us':
            window.location.host = domain_and_tld;
            break;
        case 'gb':
            window.location.host = `${domain_and_tld}?currency=GBP`;
            break;
        case 'fr':
            window.location.host = `${domain_and_tld}?currency=EUR`;
            break;
    };
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If your code runs whenever your page is loaded, then it will keep performing the reload operations.

Comment: So what should I do ?

Comment: There are many possibilities; without seeing more code or knowing more about your application it's hard to say exactly. You could add a parameter to prevent performing the `fetch()` operation after you've done that once, for example.

Comment: I try to show price in the country currency of the visitors (EUR for France visitors, GBP for UK visitors) without them having to click on a button. So the fetch function get me the country of the visitor and I want to redirected him to store_url/?currency=EUR.  or store_url/?currency=GBP. In Shopify, adding ?currency=EUR at the end of the url get us the right currency. Can you write me little bit of code ?  I am very bad with coding in general. I implore your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to change the query params based on the users country. We don't need to change `window.location.host`. You can change query params using `window.location.search`.

However, you only want to change `window.location.search` if it does not match your desired value (to avoid reloading infinitely). The solution below assumes currency is the only query param in your URL.

```
fetch('https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country')
.then(response => response.text())
.then(country_code => {

    const country_code = country_code.trim().toLowerCase();
    let desiredSearchParams = '';

    switch (country_code) {
        
        case 'gb':
            desiredSearchParams = `?currency=GBP`;
            break;
        case 'fr':
            desiredSearchParams = `?currency=EUR`;
            break;
        case 'us':
        default:   
            break;  
    };
    
    if(desiredSearchParams !== window.location.search) {
       //change search param only if desired search param different from current search param
       window.location.search = desiredSearchParams;
    }
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you  it worked! Thanks a lot have a great day! :)